# Failed to build gem native extension - During Rails Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails, but I keep getting this error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I don't know what to do, I've tried searching online for answers, such as installing command line tools, gcc, and others I can't remember, but to no effect. I often get errors doing things that others have said are suppose to resolve the problem too.

Here is the entire error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:500:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:599:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us what you tried in order for us not to suggest those same things back at you.

Comment: Also - what operating system are you on - given this is about installing software - that will change the advice we would give.

Comment: However - it all boils down to this message: "You have to install development tools first." - figure out how to do that on your OS and you'll have solved your problem